# css jquery sticky navbar foreground

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

I am trying to add sticky navbar to my "Lexus Extroic" opencart template. It is very difficult. My code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        var topDist = $("#header-layout").position();
        if (scroll > topDist.top) {
            $('nav').css({"position":"fixed","top":"0"});
        } else {
            $('nav').css({"position":"static","top":"auto"});
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

But the result is not good. Here is the result's page:
http://45.55.74.161/index.php?route=common/home

And here is my original template:
http://azbay.az

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Sticky navigation is super tricky. You should use bootstrap (a css library) and apply the navigation class "navbar-fixed-top" to always keep it at the top of the page.